# Is there a way to disable paypal Pay Later options on checkout using REST API?

Tags: php, api, rest, paypal, backend

I'm using the paypal REST API using PHP as backend. And the challenge I have is the pay in 4 and pay monthly options while I want instant full payment for less than 100$.
Is there a way to disable it while calling the API to set the limit higher for pay later?

[Image showing Paypal Pay later options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K1yqa.png)

I am selling digital products (Airtime and internet bundles) so I want instant payment. Your help is appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: The problem I had is solved. I didn't know that paypal pays the merchant and deals with the user later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Within the PayPal.com checkout, all the funding sources result in the receiver receiving a single payment. All the receiving account will know is that it received a successful PayPal payment. All billing details and information about the funding source used -- be it a card, bank, Pay Later, or any other local funding source -- are not visible to the receiving account, and kept private by design.

Using the JS SDK, it is possible to enable and control the display of the Pay Later button as well as other payment method buttons/messaging on your own site. However, this only affects what is displayed on your own site. It does not change what may or may not be available in the PayPal.com checkout page depending on the country and location of the payer, currency, amount, and intent of the transaction, etc.